# Minimize emacs on Windows with Meta-Space, n?

Tags: microsoft-windows, frames

I'd like to minimize emacs on Windows, when I press the **Alt-Space**, then **n** keys, just like with other Windows programs (because **Alt-Space** opens the program's menu that includes the 'Mi_n_imize' option, and 'n' then tells Windows to minimize that program/window)

I've rebound my left alt to be my Meta key.

So I want to set things up so that **Meta-Space n** will invoke `(suspend-frame)`

I tried this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-SPC n") 'suspend-frame)
```

But I got the error message `Key sequence M-SPC n starts with non-prefix key M-SPC`

Is there a clear explanation of what 'prefix' vs. 'non-prefix' keys are?

Is there a way to work around this, and to use Meta-Space in a key sequence?

UPDATE: I've found [the GNU Emacs manual entry for prefix keys](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Keys.html) as well as [this Wiki page on adding prefix keys](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PrefixKey) but the following doesn't work:

```
(define-prefix-command 'keymap-meta-space)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-SPC") 'keymap-meta-space )
(define-key keymap-meta-space (kbd "M-n") 'suspend-frame)
```

After evaluating all three sexp's I press M-SPC, then I press n, and then emacs waits for me to press something else (by displaying `M-SPC n-` in the minibuffer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>M-SPC</kbd> is bound to `just-one-space` by default, which is a command, not a prefix key. In order to be able to bind <kbd>M-SPC n</kbd>, you'd have to unbind it first:

```
(global-unset-key (kbd "M-SPC"))
(global-set-key (kbd "M-SPC n") #'suspend-frame)
```

Comment: I must have been doing something wrong before - when I add those three lines to my init.el (the (define-prefix-command...) etc) everything seems to work fine (even without the (global-unset-key)  ).  Any ideas what that would be?

Comment: If I understand things correctly it seems reasonable that my 3 lines would just replace M-SPC with a new keymap, thus not requiring a global-unset-key

Comment: Emacs will automatically create new keymaps for prefixes, so you don't need to define them by hand.

Comment: I thought so too.  But this: ``(global-set-key (kbd "M-SPC n") 'suspend-frame )`` produces the error message ``"Key sequence M-SPC n starts with non-prefix key M-SPC"``

Comment: Ha ha, I finally put 2 and 2 together.  First I do ``global-unset-key`` like you said, then I do a normal ``(global-set-key (kbd "M-SPC n") 'suspend-frame )`` and everything works great.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Is it appropriate to ask you to edit your answer to include that second step, just so it's super-clear to anyone reading/skimming through here what needs to be done?  If not then no worries :)

Comment: @MikeTheTall there you go.

Answer (score 2):

This actually did work, once I put it into my init.el and restarted emacs:

```
(define-prefix-command 'keymap-meta-space)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-SPC") 'keymap-meta-space )
(define-key keymap-meta-space (kbd "n") 'suspend-frame)

; and, just in case I don't release the Meta key fast enough:
(define-key keymap-meta-space (kbd "M-n") 'suspend-frame)
```